# Test equality of two objects on testing

Tags: c#, xunit

I have the following class:

```
public class OrderRule {
  public OrderDirection Direction { get; }
  public String Property { get; }
}
```

I created an Unit Test using XUnit as follows:

```
public void TryParse_ParseAscendingOrderRule() {

  OrderRule expect = new OrderRule("name", OrderDirection.Ascending);

  OrderRule result = factory.GetOrderRule("type1");

  Assert.Equal(result, expect);

}
```

I know expect and result have the same Direction and Property values but I still get False on my test ... I suppose this is because they are not the same instance ...

Do I really need to compare the Direction and Property as follows?

```
  Assert.True(result.Property == expect.Property && expect.Property == expect.Property );
```

This can become really long when the objects have many properties ...

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not necessary for `OrderRule` to be a class then make it a struct which by default implements value equality. There is also a whole MSDN [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183755.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) about value equality which might help you.

Comment: Then just overwrite 'Equals' and do the comparison once - your xUnit tests then will stay clean. There is also a good example for that on the referenced MSDN page